# Communicate with object inside a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I want to know how or even if its required in my case to communicate with an object running inside a Task.

I have a collection of processes, which are generic objects that perform some long running monitoring and calculating:

```
private IEnumerable<IService> _services;
```

Since they are based on a common interface they implement a method to "doSomeWork". So for arguments sakes lets call that method DoWork.

I want these methods all to run in a separate task space and not block sequentially, so I am spinning up a task list at a similar scope level to run this part of the program.

```
private List<Task> ProcessTask = new List<Task>();
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private CancellationToken token;

private void startAll()
{
    token = tokenSource.Token;
    ProcessTask = _services.Select(service => Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => StartService(service),
    token, 
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
    TaskScheduler.Current)).ToList();
}
```

The startservice method basically starts the monitoring and work on the individual item:

```
private void StartService(IService plugin)
{
   ...
   ...
   plugin.DoWork();
   ...
   ...
}
```

The services also have a method to "stop" and "continue", which leads to my question.  In the heart of using tasks would I be best trying to find a way of influencing the service from withing the task using an event or delegate and pausing/stopping the task or just calling these methods on the item from the external _services collection?

e.g.:

```
_services.ForEach(item => item.Stop());
```

If it is the former then how do I raise an event inside the task from out side, or should I monitor an external flag?

Comment: you have to introduce a kind of context for each task that the task and the outside world knows. the task must check periodically whether the flag has some special value set by the outside and act upon it.

Comment: Thanks @Mario, So I could add something like a ConcurrentQueue or blocking collection to the class level to send a message from which the task collects?

Comment: yes, just keep concurrency in mind and locking - also remeber that a ConcurrentQueue will be slower than an integer flag - which you can set and check with Increment.xxxx operations. but that depends on how performance critical you really are - if not, just keep it simple.

Comment: @Mario, Thank you, I'm happy to use things like the InterLock.Exchange/ increment. Although in the heart of the task context is there a way that I could attach some kind of an event that raises into the Task?

Comment: Event not really, since the event mechanism uses a thread on its own, or at least not the thread in which the DoWork task is running - and I suppose you want that thread to get some notification.

Comment: Correct I do, Seems a more elegant approach. If possible that is.  That flag works for me too, but am hoping that's the fallback plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CancellationToken` as a one-shot event:

```
token.Register(() => item.Stop())
```

Hopefully, this will work with your particular "service" API. Note, that the token can fire before the service starts and also after you are done.

Comment: seems to have worked. At least for one method. However do I need a new token for each item the list?

Comment: You need one token per distinct cancellation event you want to perform.

Comment: Thank you, I have create a simple wrapper poco which has a token and a "service" element. I've adapted my statement to use this wrapper and 1:1 token and service.  All is well in the world.

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer the first question I had, which was about how to post something into the thread, sofar I think I would have to follow @usr point.  However for this example of what I needed the register was good enough. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you want to post something into the thread but how is that supposed to work if the thread is doing something else? I don't really understand how your "service" works. In general it is rare to find true thread affinity. Often, it doesn't matter much on which thread things run as long as the synchronization is set up properly. (Big exception would be UI threads. Not here.) I think this is the only answer possible given the information.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution code is:
My new container class

```
internal class ServiceContainer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Process service which runs the monitor
    /// </summary>
    public IService ServiceProcess { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cancellation token used to cancel the operation
    /// </summary>
    public CancellationTokenSource CancelTokenSource { get; private set; }

    internal ProcessContainer(IService plugin)
    {
        this.PluginProcess = plugin;
        CancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```

Then create a list of service wrappers:

```
serviceWrapperList = _plugins.Select(service => new ServiceContainer(service)).ToList();
```

Then I get my task running and based service set:

```
ProcessTaskList = serviceWrapperList.Select(serviceSet => Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                IService service = serviceSet.ServiceProcess;
                CancellationToken token = serviceSet.CancelTokenSource.Token;
                StartService(service);
                token.Register(() => StopPlugin(service));
            },
            serviceSet.CancelTokenSource.Token,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Current)).ToList();
```

Finally I have my stop all method.

```
    protected void StopAllServices()
    {
        ProcessTaskList.ForEach(f => f.CancelTokenSource.Cancel());
    }
```